# Neo4J object not saved on second save with KafkaListener

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, spring-data

I have a producer that send some object in Kafka (Spring Boot Application)
I have a consumer with neo4j configured (I'm using Spring-Data with Spring Boot)

The code of the Listener:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class KafkaReceiver {

  @Autowired
  AssetService assetService;

  @Transactional
  @KafkaListener(topics = "portfolio")
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?,?> consumerRecord) throws Exception{
    log.debug("################## START RECEIVE ");
    String value = consumerRecord.value().toString();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    log.debug("@@@@@@@ OBJECTS BEFORE : " + assetService.count());
    Asset asset = objectMapper.readValue(value, Asset.class);
    Asset s = assetService.addAsset(asset);
    log.debug("@@@@@@@ OBJECTS AFTER : " + assetService.count());

    log.debug("################## END RECEIVE ");
  }
 }
```

and the code of the AssetService:

```
   @Service
   public class AssetService {
      @Autowired
      AssetRepository assetRepository;

      @Autowired
      Session neo4jSession;

      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
      public Asset addAsset(Asset asset){
        Asset s = assetRepository.save(asset);
        return s;
      }

      @Transactional(readOnly = true)
      public long count(){
        return assetRepository.count();
       }
   }
```

(The full code is also available on github: https://github.com/jonleb/assetmanager)

When I run the application, the first time that the listener consume the service, data is persisted in the neo4j but afterward it is not the case. I have to restart the application to store again an object. 
I don't understand why. I try to change transaction but after 1 day of research I don't have any new idea.

Could you help me?

Thanks